# Can I use a 70A panel on a 30A feeder breaker?

Tags: electrical, subpanel, shed, uf-b

Since the Eaton 70 amp 2 space 4 circuit breaker box I have only lists 8 to 2 gauge wire can I still install my 10/3 UF cable with a double pole 20 to make 2 120v circuits in my shed?

I have a preexisting double pole 30 amp breaker in my service panel with about a 100” of 10/3 UF cable already in the ground. At the shed where I had a single 20amp 120v circuit being fed by the 10/3 and 30amp breaker in my main panel I just had the second hot wire capped off.

Is it safe and legal to put the 70amp box with a double pole in the shed and add a double pole 20A breaker to put the second hot to use and get a second circuit making a MWBC?

Comment: I edited a bit to try to make this more clear and readable. Please make sure I didn't change the intent or facts of your question. If so, please [edit] again to clarify. Remember, we can only give you accurate advice if we fully understand your question, so clear communication is important. Also, please take the [tour] to learn more about how this site works (we're a little different than most discussion fora on the internet).

Comment: Also, we know that it's an Eaton panel, specifying _exactly_ which model will help people better help you.

Answer (score 2):

No, you may not attach 10AWG wire to lugs that are rated for sizes 8AWG-2AWG only. You could pigtail from the #10 to a wire size that the lugs accept, or find a different panel that accepts #10 on its lugs.

Another option (using a larger panel) would be to back-feed (and bolt down) a two-pole breaker that accepts #10 wire. Any size (even breaker-format two-pole switch, such a QO makes) would be fine since the #10 wire is protected by the 30A breaker in your main panel.

You may wish to consider two separate single-pole breakers instead of a two-pole 20A breaker if you have receptacles and lights in the shed, so that situations like tripping a breaker with a power tool don't also put you in the dark. Or go with a larger panel so you can have two receptacle circuits and a third for lighting.

It is always fine to use a panel with a higher rating than the feeder size. The rating is a maximum limit that must not be exceeded, not a minimum that must be met. You could legally put a 200A 40-space panel on your 30A feeder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can oversize the capacity of your subpanels.

In fact a common piece of advice we give here is to massively oversize panels and subpanels, because number of spaces is more important. That is perfectly fine as long as the breaker feeding the subpanel is appropriately sized for the wires doing the feeding. (A 30A breaker protecting the 10/3 in your case).